# Recursive solution for an Object in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I am solving a kata at codewars.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5540e75396737c4cea000092/train/javascript

I am able to solve the kata but I can't refactor my code for the correct output of function

QUESTİON Description

Find the needle(s) in a haystack by creating a function that returns all properties (recursively) which contains the needle (string).

Return value should be a sorted array.

```js
function search(haystack, needle, arr = []) {
    for (let key in haystack) {
        const keyOne = haystack[key]
        if (typeof keyOne === 'string' && keyOne.indexOf(needle) !== -1) {
            key
            arr.push(keyOne[key]??=key)
        }
        else if (typeof keyOne === 'object' ) {
            search(keyOne, needle, arr)
        }
    }
    return arr
}



const obj = {
    site: "Codewars",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit...",
    obj2: {
        str: "Yeah, Codewars!",
        num: 123,
        obj3: {
            something: "Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Codewars R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn. Gotha fm'latgh h'gof'nn, geb chtenff"
        }
    }
};

console.log(search(obj, 'Codewars')) //results =[ 'site', 'str', 'something' ]
```

But my solution  must return the output with this exact output

```js
["obj2.obj3.something", "obj2.str", "site"]
```

So is there an any hint or trick that anybody can you show me to grasp more Js logic ?

Comment: Please post a description of the problem here, not just a link.

Comment: You're never concatenating the keys of the parent objects.

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Pass the path as an extra argument. When you find the property, concatenate it to the path. And when you call the function recursively, concatenate the property name to the path.

Comment: *"I am able to solve the kata but I can't refactor my code for the correct output of function"*: this is self-contradicting. if you don't get the correct output, you haven't solved the code challenge. A code challenge is solved when your code produces the correct output for all test cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code passes the tests.
Thnks to everbody

```js
function search(haystack, needle, arr = [], path = []) {
    for (let key in haystack) {
        const keyOne = haystack[key]
        if (typeof keyOne === 'string' && keyOne.indexOf(needle) !== -1) {
            key
            arr.push(path.join`.` + '.' + key)
        }
        else if (typeof keyOne === 'object' ) {
            search(keyOne, needle, arr, path.concat(key))
        }
    }
    return arr.map(e => e.startsWith('.') ? e.slice(1) : e).sort()
}

const obj = {
    site: "Codewars",
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit...",
    obj2: {
        str: "Yeah, Codewars!",
        num: 123,
        obj3: {
            something: "Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Codewars R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn. Gotha fm'latgh h'gof'nn, geb chtenff"
        }
    }
};

console.log(search(obj, 'Codewars')) // results ==>> [ 'obj2.obj3.something', 'obj2.str', 'site' ]
```

Comment: Remember that answers are for actual answers: if you're going to post one, make sure to explain what was wrong, what the fix is, and _then_ show the corresponding now-working code =)

Comment: but also: you definitely need to work on both naming things and reading up on modern JS because `keyOne` is really just `value`, but a lot of what you've written is a fairly outdated: `for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(haystack))` lets you iterate over key-value pairs, which is what you want. Also, `if (value.contains?.(needle))` using both the modern String `contains` and optional chaining. Also just use a string for your path, expand it immediately (```const newpath = `${path ? `${path}.` : ``}${key}`)``` and then arr.push and recurse with that.